# What is the risk of including UnityClasses into Android Project?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins

I am working on an Unity Plugin for Android and I learned that unity's classes.jar can be included into Android Project

- To get handle to current Activity in Android (UnityPlayer.currentActivity)
- To pass notifications to Unity(UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage())

However this means my android project needs to have reference (compile time) to unity's classes.jar. Currently the only way to extract this is from Unity installed on my machine.

- Is it safe to have this dependency in my Android project?
- Will the calls for CurrentActivity and SendMessage keep changing with new Unity versions?
- Is there a global repo (maven/jcenter) that I can use to get latest classes.jar?

This is my first unity project, suggestions/hints are highly appreciated.

~thanks